# If there a pointers in lisp programming?

Tags: pointers, lisp

I don`t have specific example code or anything. I just want to know if there is a pointers in lisp. If there is please share a simple example

Comment: No, Lisp doesn't have pointers. Many Lisp implementations have them as extensions, so that some of the built-in functions can be written in Lisp and interface with the underlying C implementation.

Comment: If there is no pointers in lisp then is there any command in lisp that can have the same concept as pointers?

Comment: I mean just like Solidity. Solidity doesn`t have switch case but you can do switch-case win a form of if-else.

Comment: Lisp values are typically implemented as pointers under the covers (except for immediate values like fixnums). But there's nothing analogous to the general pointers you find in languages like C. They're only pointers to the whole object, there's nothing like a pointer to a specific array element.

Comment: Of course, you can do `(cons array index)` at a higher level. And in fact, this is how Lisp Machine C implemented C pointers. But it doesn't generalize -- you can't use the same notation to get a pointer to a specific cell in a cons.

Comment: How can I use (cons array index) as pointers? Can you please give me an example.

Answer (score 3):

Lisp doesn't have actual pointers. But as per the [fundamental theorem of software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering) we can emulate them by adding a level of indirection. We can use a container of some kind, such as a cons cell or defstruct.

```
(defstruct pointer
    array
    offset)
(defun pointer-deref (ptr)
  (aref (pointer-array ptr) (pointer-offset ptr)))
(defun set-pointer-deref (ptr value)
  (setf (aref (pointer-array ptr) (pointer-offset ptr)) value))
(defsetf pointer-deref set-pointer-deref)

(defvar my-array (vector 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
(defvar my-ptr (make-pointer :array my-array :offset 3))
(print (pointer-deref my-ptr)) ; prints 4
(setf (pointer-deref my-ptr) 20)
(print my-array) ; prints #(1 2 3 20 5 6 7 8 9 10)
(incf (pointer-offset my-ptr))
(print (pointer-defer my-ptr)) ; prints 5
(defvar my-array-2 (vector 15 30 40))
(setf (pointer-array my-ptr) my-array-2 (pointer-offset my-ptr) 0)
(print (pointer-deref my-ptr)) ; prints 15
```

The above code is roughly analogous to this C code:

```
int my_array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
int *my_ptr = &my_array[3];
printf("%d\n", *my_ptr);
*my_ptr = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  printf("%d ", my_array[i]);
}
my_ptr++;
printf("%d\n", *my_ptr);
int my_array2[] = {15, 30, 40};
my_ptr = &my_array2[0];
printf("%d\n", *my_ptr);
```

In keeping with Lisp's dynamic typing, these pointers can point to any type of data, you don't have to declare the type. On the other hand, this implementation only supports pointers to array elements, whereas C pointers can also point to variables and structure members. A more complex implementation could use CLOS to define different classes of pointers, with generic functions to allow you to use them consistently. This could also solve some of the pointer safety problems in C; they can check that the offsets are in range, prevent incrementing pointers that aren't to array elements, etc.